# Have a model with an object I want to connect to two other models (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I need the "eventList" to connect to both "Event" and "customEvent". I'm not sure how to declare the ManyToManyFields on it. What I have right now is:

```
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(Event, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE", related_name='event_set+')
    eventList = models.ManyToManyField(customEvent, blank="TRUE", null="TRUE")
```

I don't think this works because it just reassigns eventList on the second line. How would I get this accomplished?

Comment: Just change the name of variable. Whats tough in that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
class EventConnect(models.Model)
    events = models.ForeignKey(MyEvent)
    eventList = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank="true", null="true", related_name='event_set+')
    customEventList = models.ForeignKey(customEvent, blank="true", null="true", related_name='customevent_set+')

    class Meta:
        unique_together('events', 'Event', 'customEvent')

class MyEvent(models.Model):
    #rest of the fields..
```

Note that `ForeignKey` is sufficient in the intermediary table. You cannot assign multiple many to many against the same model field. (like assigning 2 different values to the same database column - which is not possible unless you manage the keys yourself.)

Comment: Sorry, I realized I wasn't 100% clear in my question. I need the eventList to connect to both.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do then.